# hyperlink in between the line

Tags: java, hyperlink, label, vaadin, vaadin7

How can I put a hyperlink for a given word in a label in Vaadin.
Example:

```
Please upload a ***gene annotation*** file:
```

In above label, "gene annotation" would be a hyperlink, which on click would either take you to a website or a local file.

I know how to do it using "link", but dont know how would I incorporate it in a sentence/label

Another example:

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-link.html

All the blue hyperlinks in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter HTML in a Label like this.

```
addComponent(new Label("Please upload a <a href='/'>gene annotation</a> file:",ContentMode.HTML));
```